# A domain with odd-dimensional boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am entirely new to this topic of inquiry and my background in algebraic/topology is fragile. However, I came upon a question I don't have an answer to.

Given any natural number $n$, is there a known example of a bounded (if not, then unbounded) domain (an open connected set) $\mathcal D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that the boundary $\partial \mathcal D$ consists of $n$ **submanifolds** of dimensions $1,3,5,\ldots,2n-1$?

If an explicit example is not known, then how can one create one? It will be very helpful if one points me in the direction that will help to create such a domain. I am willing to take a course on a topic if it is required.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Take a topologically disjoint union of open disks of dimensions $2,4,6,\dots,2n$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I can't understand how the union is a domain (open connected set) of dimension $2n$. I require $\mathcal D$ to be a domain (an open connected set) in $\mathbb R ^{2n}$.

Comment: Start with an open round ball $B^{2n}$ in $R^{2n}$. Then inductively remove from it a round sphere of dimension $2n-3$ (contained in the intersection of $B^{2n}$ with an affine  subspace of dimension $2n-2$), then remove a round sphere of dimension $2n-5$, etc... Make sure that the subsets you are removing are pairwise disjoint.